# LARAVEL 8 -> Formulario POST no activa la ruta

Tags: php, laravel-8

estoy haciendo una página a mi hermano y puse dos un formulario para que la gente pueda preguntar cosas a la empresa. Bueno, al enviar el formulario por POST le digo a web.php que abra el HomeController y abra el método llamado user.question, el cual dentro tiene código. Lo curioso, es que no se si el código de user.question está malo ya que ni si quiera logra abrirlo, esto lo se debido a que intenté poner un view de otra cosa y me seguía abriendo el index.

El resultado es que no pasa nada, sólo recarga la página y ya. No sale ningún mensaje de error en los @error.

[image: En esta parte tengo el formulario, la ruta es user.question]

[image: Ya puse el @csrf del blade]

[image: El modelo de Eloquent]

[image: También intenté con FormRequest]

[image: Acá el web.php]

[image: a]

De antemano, agradezco la ayuda! He estado ya 3 horas buscando el problema jajaj

Comment: No añadas imágenes con código fuente, el código va como texto.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios errores que noto revisando tu código:

1. Debes instanciar el objeto pregunta y no pasarlo por parámetro.
2. Para fijarte que tiene la variable $pregunta dentro te recomiendo hacer en el método lo siguiente:

   var_dump($pregunta);

   die();
3. Si el var_dump te llega el objeto nulo, debes tener algún error a la hora de hacer la plantilla blade o algún error de sintaxis en el controlador.

Comment: Para evitar esos dos comandos, en Laravel tenemos a `dd`

Comment: @alfonsoarmie efectivamente, el error estaba en la función question, al parecer cambió la sintaxis que yo conocía de $request->validate(), volví a Instanciar $pregunta y me funcionó al devolver el view. Gracias por tu respuesta!